# ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalablefonts

Tags: fonts

I already installed cm-super and the error occurs when I try to compile the document with
\usepackage{opensans}
instead of
\usepackage{lmodern}
I updated all packages and checked the logfile to make sure cm-super is installed correctly:
s/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>

Comment: there exist other bitmap fonts. Remove microtype, compile and then check at the end of the log-file which font is in pk-format.

Comment: I am not really sure what do u mean by microtype?
I deleted the package: \usepackage[tracking=true,spacing=true,kerning=true,final]{microtype}
Now it doesnt fail to produce the pdf

Comment: But as you probably want to use microtype you need to find out which font it doesn't like. So check the end of the log file.

Comment: I am sorry I cant make sense out of the lofile:
MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cmbright
/dpi525\cmbr8.pk> 
Is that what your were looking for?

Comment: you will have to make a short but complete example which uses this font. Then I can test with my miktex.

Comment: What do u mean by  "which uses this font"?

Comment: the cmbr8.pk you found in the log.

Comment: I dont really know which part of my paper is used by this cmbr8.pk
So it is difficult for me to make an example where this font is used

Comment: Move \end{document} to the middle of your document. Compile. If the font is still there you know that it is the first half of your document. Continue until your found the place.

Comment: My paper is more then 150 pages long, so that will take time.
Instead I can show you an example on when the error occurs:
This is an example for a sentence I can not write in my paper $15,8m^3$ und $4,5 m^3$.
This is an example for a sentence I can write in my paper $15,8m^3$ und \\ $4,5 m^3$.
So if i add manually a new line the file produces a pdf without an error. This only accours when i use mathmatical signs

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{scrbook}
%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cmbright}% Schriftfamilie ComputerModern Bright (serifenlos)

\usepackage[tracking=true,spacing=true,kerning=true,final]{microtype}% optischer 

\begin{document}
 
This is an example for a sentence I can not write in my paper $15,8m^3$ und $4,5 m^3$ for example
 
\end{document}

Comment: this example needs the hfbright package.

Comment: Sepcifcally, the bitmap font created with METAFONT is the math (and possibly OT1) font from `\usepackage{cmbright}`. If you install the `hfbright` package (which should not require changing your source), your document should compile with `microtype`.